# Calling R from a C++ program (in Linux)

Tags: c++, r, linux

What am I doing wrong here? When I call `Rscript` directly like this

```
/home/vagrant/bin/Rscript -e "x <- 2; x+1"
```

I get this output

> [1] 3

When I call `Rscript` from my C++ program using `execl()`, I error out.

The code snippet for calling `Rscript` is below

```
void callR_dummy(int i) {
  int errval = execl("/home/vagrant/bin/Rscript", "-e", "x <- 2; x+1", (char*) NULL);
  int err = errno;
  cout <<"callR " << i << " : errno = " << err << endl;
}
```

I get

> Fatal error: cannot open file 'x <- 2; x+1': No such file or directory

And before someone suggests writing R extensions, that's not an option for me, I am restricted on that.
And before somebody marks this a duplicate again, no it is not. NO EXTENSIONS ARE NOT AN OPTION.

Comment: Escape the quote characters in the 3rd argument

Answer (score 0):

```
int errval = execl("/home/vagrant/bin/Rscript", "-e", "\"x <- 2; x+1\"", (char*) NULL);
```

Comment: I tried that variation too. Now, to be sure, switching to `system()` does the trick but I am really curious why `execl()` fails.

Comment: Because it passes your arguments as is. R needs the quotes around the raw code you are passing to it in the command line otherwise it thinks it's a location of a file